# Is the vim-daily launchpad.net PPA still functioning?

Tags: linux-ubuntu

It says on vim PPA manager [Jonathon F's launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejonathonf) that:

> *"This account belonged to a deceased user and has been archived."*

(In fact, Jonathon F. [died in January of 2023](https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/jonathon-passed-away/35814).)

But on the [vim-daily PPA page](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/vim-daily), it can be seen that vim has been updated
as of ***01 December 2023*** for Ubuntu versions 22.04.1, 20.04.1 and 18.04.1:

*vim    2:9.0.0749+really.v9.0.2143-0york0~ubuntu22.04.1    Jonathon F (2023-12-01)*

So, it appears that ***someone*** is still updating the vim-daily PPA.

However, I have had vim-daily in my /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ for some time and my vim has been stuck for a few weeks now at version 9.0.1837, and has not upgraded to 9.0.2143.

I've checked to make sure I have the source entry correct, but updated vims are not being installed. If vim is being updated on the PPA, the updates should install on my machine.

Does anyone know what's going on with this?  Thanks.

Comment: The builds [appear](https://code.launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+recipe/vim-daily) to be automated, as they should, if you ask me.